# Java CVS library

Tags: java, api, cvs

Do anyone know if there is a library which provides an API for Java to manage CVS repositories (for example to checkout a path)?

I have found JavaCVS (from NetBeans) and a project called JCVS but both are unavailable.

Comment: How so? http://javacvs.sourceforge.net/ is available, no?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: From their site: "JavaCVS is currently in early development and design although many of the CVS commands are now supported and it can also display differences between files graphically. It is anticipated that by September 2001 a beta version will be available supporting most common functionality." . That doesn't really count as "available" in my view :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can download the CVS Client library  used by the netbeans at [here](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/downloads/) . It is 100% Pure Java Standalone CVS Client Library.

For the documentation and sample code , you can visit [here](http://versioncontrol.netbeans.org/javacvs/library/)